# dottrace and optimizing method with indexof

Tags: c#, performance-testing, dottrace

```
public static string[] GetStringInBetween(string strBegin, string strEnd, string strSource, bool includeBegin, bool includeEnd)
        {
            string[] result = { "", "" };
            int iIndexOfBegin = strSource.IndexOf(strBegin);

            if (iIndexOfBegin != -1)
            {
                // include the Begin string if desired
                if (includeBegin)
                    iIndexOfBegin -= strBegin.Length;

                strSource = strSource.Substring(iIndexOfBegin + strBegin.Length);
                int iEnd = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd);

                if (iEnd != -1)
                {
                    // include the End string if desired
                    if (includeEnd)
                        iEnd += strEnd.Length;

                    result[0] = strSource.Substring(0, iEnd);

                    // advance beyond this segment
                    if (iEnd + strEnd.Length < strSource.Length)
                        result[1] = strSource.Substring(iEnd + strEnd.Length);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

usage:

```
string[] result = null;
result = HtmlHelper.GetStringInBetween(bits[0], bits[1], tagValuePair.Value, true, true);
```

i am using dottrace and this method use 33% of my CPU. How can i optimize it. Becouse of it my application crash or i get out of memory. Is it smart that this method is static?

dottrace show 30% usage of cpu on this:

```
System.String.IndexOf(String, Int32, Int32, StringComparison)
```

[image]

EDIT:

```
    GetStringInBetween(string strBegin, string strEnd, string strSource, bool includeBegin, bool includeEnd)

strBegin = "<td class=\"m92_t_col2\">"
strEnd = "</td>"
strSource = "xxxxxxxx<td class=\"m92_t_col2\">Di. 31.01.12</td>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
includeBegin = true
includeEnd = true

then i will get result
result[0] = "<td class=\"m92_t_col2\">Di. 31.01.12</td>"
```

hope this helps what this method do. Try to find string between strBegin and strEnd...

Comment: Have you considered using a regular expression for this?

Comment: @Oded i did but i am very bad with regex so i write code with indexof which i see now was bad idea ...

Comment: Does dottrace tell you that the calls to `System.String.IndexOf(String, Int32, Int32, StringComparison)` is coming from `GetStringInBetween` If it is can you simply reduce the calls to `GetStringInBetween`

Comment: yes it is from GetStringInBetween. How can i reduce the code? I don't know regex well

Comment: Regular expressions are very much tied to the text they operate on - it is impossible to suggest one without knowing more about the kind of input.

Comment: So the input is always HTML fragments?

Comment: most of the time yes. i am testing something lik Match m = Regex.Match(html, "<head>(.*)</head>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying part of the string (your first SubString call) just to keep searching in it is bad for performance. Instead, keep your original input string but use the overload on IndexOf that takes a start index and then adjust your index calculation for extracting the result accordingly.

Also, knowing that these strings are not localized, you might gain some by using an ordinal comparer in IndexOf.

Something along the lines of

```
public static string[] GetStringInBetween(string strBegin, string strEnd, string strSource, bool includeBegin, bool includeEnd)
{
    string[] result = { "", "" };
    int iIndexOfBegin = strSource.IndexOf(strBegin, StringComparison.Ordinal);

    if (iIndexOfBegin != -1)
    {
        int iEnd = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, iIndexOfBegin, StringComparison.Ordinal);

        if (iEnd != -1)
        {
            result[0] = strSource.Substring(
                iIndexOfBegin + (includeBegin ? 0 : strBegin.Length), 
                iEnd + (includeEnd ? strEnd.Length : 0) - iIndexOfBegin);

            // advance beyond this segment
            if (iEnd + strEnd.Length < strSource.Length)
                result[1] = strSource.Substring(iEnd + strEnd.Length);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'll have to post another answer since there's not enough room here. oh, wait - I can edit.

Answer (score 0):

For your sample input, it appears you are working with HTML fragments.

I suggest using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML - it exposes the result in an easy to query fashion, using LINQ to XML or XPath type syntax. It is a fast and efficient library.